# Swagger-codegen generated code having issues Routing requests with parameters in path

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-tools

I created my api definition using swagger and have generated the server code using Swagger-tools in NodeJs. The SwaggerRouter handles all routes properly excepts the routes with ID.
For example , routes like

/v1/factoris/self
/v1/factoris/create

are directed to the right controller
but calls with IDs

/v1/factoris/{factoris_id}

are returned as invalid routes.

Any idea what I might be missing ?

Here is a sample of the swagger specs

```
/factoris/create:
post:
  tags:
  - "Factoris"
  summary: "Create New Factori"
  description: ""
  operationId: "factorisCreatePOST"
  parameters:
  - in: "body"
    name: "FactoriCreate"
    description: "Create a new factory"
    required: true
    schema:
      $ref: "#/definitions/FactoriCreate"
  responses:
    201:
      description: "A single factori object"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/inline_response_201"
    405:
      description: "Method not allowed"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/inline_response_405"
  security:
  - oauth2:
    - "admin"
  x-swagger-router-controller: "Factoris"

/factoris/{factori-id}:
get:
  tags:
  - "Factoris"
  summary: "Factori Information"
  description: ""
  operationId: "factorisFactori_idGET"
  parameters:
  - name: "factori-id"
    in: "path"
    description: "The factori identifier string"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  - name: "expand"
    in: "query"
    description: "Provide expanded information on Assemblies or Products or Users"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "A single factori object"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/inline_response_201"
    404:
      description: "Factori not found"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/inline_response_404"
  security:
  - oauth2:
    - "codeadmin"
  x-swagger-router-controller: "Factoris"
```

Comment: Pls report the issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the swagger codegen community can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I figured out that  path parameter does not work if its has a "-" (factori-id)
so changing factori-id to factori_id fixed it.  But its still a bug since the path parameter cannot handle "-"

here is the open issue created in Swagger-codegen
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5763